# Measure the frames per second on a mac

Tags: mac, video

Is there a tool for mac to measure the frames per second ?

Or Could I just know how many frames per second are displayed on a MacBookPro ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you're measuring.  The screen refreshes from video memory, and the video memory is modified by the OS or by OpenGL commands executing on the GPU.

If you run two quicktime movies side by side, the will separately update the video memory, and could have two different frame rates based on the system load and several other factors.

Any tools to measure framerate would need to measure just one applications framerate.  Many applications, such as video players and video games, can report their own framerate.

Further, any software tool will consume system resources that may affect framerate.

When I've had to objectively measure framerate for an app that didn't measure and report framerate itself I've used a high speed camera (for consumers the PS3 camera is considered high speed) and then examined the frames of video for display updates to determine the framerate.

The Macbook Pro display refreshes 60 frames per second, and no faster framerate can be displayed on it. These techniques would only measure framerates below 60.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually application-provided or developer-tool provided. If you want to know for some particular application look for a developer console or other debug output. If you are a developer, use the OpenGL tools in Xcode's Instruments such as OpenGL Profiler.

You need to get this information from the application because it is the only thing that can count how many times it is refreshing display per second. the hardware refresh goes on regardless, if nothing changed in the frame buffer it gets refreshed anyway.

"About This Mac" used to show the hardware refresh rate for each display but doesn't appear to any more. It is almost certainly 60 or 75 Hz for your internal LCD.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [Apple's OpenGL Profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLProfilerUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for something like this by attaching it to a process and then seeing what values it displays for the frame rate. You can get it at [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/).